# htaccess - dynamic Baseurl generated from subsubdomain

Tags: .htaccess, dynamic

unfortunately I don't know how to start.

I have the following file structure:

```
.htaccess   
  |- site1
    |- .htpasswd
    |- index.php
  |- site2
    |- .htpasswd
    |- index.php
```

So I need a dynamically baseurl depending on the sub-subdomain.

When I enter http://site1.preview.domain.com I want the baseurl pointing to site1.preview.domain.com/site1. But in browser it should still be http://site1.preview.domain.com

Furthermore I want to protect each "site"-folder. So is it possible to dynamicly point to the htpasswd?

Thanks in advance for suggestions.

Comment: `.htpasswd` always needs full filesystem path

Comment: ok, thx for that info. Any ideas regarding the other point?

Answer (score 0):

In the root .htaccess you can have this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(site1|site2)\.preview\. [NC]
RewriteRule !^(site1|site2)/ %1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```